# Steps in deploying a python script in google scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I tried multiple ways to make my python file run every day using scheduler but doesn't work.

I have put this script in the URL: [https://storage.cloud.google.com/[mybucket_name]/[mypython].py](https://storage.cloud.google.com/%5Bmybucket_name%5D/%5Bmypython%5D.py)

I also upload my credential json in the same bucket so that I can make sure the credential can be accessed in the line of :

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('sxxx-78322-c501d23cec38.json')
```

I configure the scheduler and then I force run this schedule job and it gave me this error:

```
insertId: "1vfeko1f3ggyvq"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
jobName: "projects/stockdata-378322/locations/europe-west2/jobs/daily-stock-extraction"
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
targetType: "HTTP"
url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/stock-data-bucket-test/stock_gcp.py"
}
logName: "projects/stockdata-378322/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-02-20T23:50:49.704520273Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2023-02-20T23:50:49.704520273Z"
}
```

This python file can run smoothly in my local machine but cannot be scheduled properly. I even replace my code to one line only, but still got this INVALID_ARGUMENT:

```
print ('hello')
```

Is it the configuration wrong?

- Target type is: HTTP
- URL is [https://storage.cloud.google.com/[mybucket_name]/[mypython].py](https://storage.cloud.google.com/%5Bmybucket_name%5D/%5Bmypython%5D.py)
- HTTP method: POST

I have not added any service account into the Auth header, does this matter? And even I have made service account the storage admin, same error.

anyone got any conclusion?

Comment: You're trying to run the python script directly off the GCS bucket?  Because you can't.

You can deploy it as a Cloud Function and trigger the CF either from HTTP POST method or from a Pub/Sub topic depending on how you set it up.

Comment: Cloud Scheduler is an eventing unit (trigger an event on a schedule). Cloud Storage is a storage unit (put objects in a bucket). If you want to perform processing, you must use a processing unit (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, GKE, App Engine,...). Review your design to use the right unit to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Like `guillaume blaquiere` and `glen yu` mentioned you can’t trigger a python script from gcs storage directly either you need to deploy it as a cloud function or cloud run. I think you have misinterpreted the google cloud docs, while creating a cloud function there is a step for uploading your code into GCS for version control and for having a backup, then you will create an entry point and a pub sub topic for your cloud scheduler to trigger the cloud function. **[Deploying your code using cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-cloud-storage)** steps in **[cloud function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#basics)**,  there is more information provided in this documentation on how to achieve this. Now once you have deployed your cloud function using gcs bucket you just need to create a trigger by using a pub/sub topic which will be used in your cloud scheduler for triggering the cloud function, follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) for more information.

Note: This solution has been framed using the information available in google cloud docs and official links are embedded into the post at respective topics.

Comment: let me have a try

Comment: the thing is that i want to for example use yfiance to create a csv in the bucket by scheduler. So the code will need to access the bucket.
    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_string(csv_data)

Comment: @ZKK can you specify this more clearly are you trying to load data from gcloud bucket or trying append lines to the existing csv file?